# Grails build path confusion

Tags: eclipse, grails, buildpath, astyanax

My question is how do I find and remove a wrong library reference from Grails app.

What happened was:

1. I have a working Grails app.
2. I added Astyanax jar to "/lib" folder and added it to the Build Path.
3. I copied the examples from the Astyanax git repo and opened them in Eclipse. Eclipse was showing errors regarding method setCqlVersion not found in a class.
4. I removed the jar from Build Path and "lib".
   Result: Eclipse does not complain about absence of library and shows me the same error regarding method not found.

This is very confusing to me - How Eclipse/Grails is finding the Astyanax library?
I have restarted Eclipse a number of times and added/removed library a few time - no luck.

Comment: I think there isn't enough information for me to go on from this.
Could you provide your full classpath?
A way to do that is to open up the ".classpath" file within the project, and copy it's content into your question.

Then I'll see all that you have within your classpath, and might be more helpful.